# Grouping by week then month using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am calculating hours worked using linq to populate a table and keeping a running total of the hours worked over the week. All is fine until I attempt to group weekly hours by month. I am hitting a snag for part time staff when the week spans 2 months as the count isnt accurate and only begins counting again middle of the week for example.

I am trying to pass the results of one linq query to another, by means of initially grouping the first result set by week, then the second result set by month. I will post a snippet of the code below, massively reduced for brevity as the week portion of the linq query performs tons of calculations, below is just bare bones. I am wondering how I can pass the month to the month calculation, without using it as part of the week calculation if that makes sense. I am capturing the weeknumber in the database as an integer to make life easy.
So to sum this up as its a bit messy. If I worked the first week of Feb this year, which began 29th Jan (week 5). How do I ensure the first few days of week 5 in january add to the total of the week5 hours in feb

```cs
var weekView = 
    from t in _db.MyTable                                     
    group t by new
    {
        t.WeekNumber,
        Month = t.ShiftDate.Month,
        t.UserId                             
    } into day
    select new
    {
        UserId = day.Key.UserId,
        Week = day.Key.WeekNumber,
        Month = day.Key.Month
        Hours = day.Where(x => x.WorkedHours > 37.5).Sum(h => h.Overtime)
    }

var weekView = 
    from t in weekView                                     
    group t by new
    {                           
        Month = month.ShiftDate.Month,
        month.UserId                             
    } into month
    select new
    {
        UserId = day.Key.UserId,                           
        Month = day.Key.Month
        Hours = day.Sum(h => h.Hours)
    }
```

Comment: How do define which month a week is in? Could you calculate the date of that day of the week and then group by the month of _that_ date?

Comment: I am capturing the date a shift was completed in the db. However, the only way I can access the month in the month query, is by passing it from the week query. I know im going the wrong way about it but a bit stuck

Comment: Could you group by week (and ID), find the max(ShiftDate) from each group (instead of grouping my months also) and then find the month of that max date?

Comment: Using `max(ShiftDate)` might *not* be reliable if your employee does not work all shifts - perhaps taking a day off on the first of the month. A better approach would be to define a mapping of ShifDate to WeekEndingDate (typically ending on a Friday, Saturday, or Sunday) and then mapping that WeekEndingDate to Month. This way, even if an employee only works the first day of the week, that activity would still map to the correct WeekEndingDate and Month. as activity for an employee who worked every day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply TN, i have mapped the end week date to the shiftdate.  However, simiar problem exists where by grouping by the endOfWeek.Month only shows the output for feb and discounts the 3 days in january of week 5

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think it cant really be done. By grouping by a specific month, you lose access to the previous months content.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I have not submitted the question as is to AI, but I have let it help me formulate my solution.

In calculating overtime, we've generated a `WeekInMonthDays` list to count the standard Monday to Friday workdays for each week within a month. This list presumes a full workweek excludes weekends but does not account for public holidays.

The LINQ query provided constructs this list, identifying the number of workdays per week, which is instrumental for the subsequent overtime calculations:

```cs
var weekInMonthDays = calendarDates
    .Where(date => date.DateValue.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Monday &&
                   date.DateValue.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Friday)
    .Select(date => new {
        Year = date.DateValue.Year,
        Month = date.DateValue.Month,
        WeekNr = (int)Math.Ceiling(date.DateValue.Day / 7.0),
        DateValue = date.DateValue
    })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month, x.WeekNr })
    .Select(g => new {
        g.Key.Year,
        g.Key.Month,
        g.Key.WeekNr,
        DaysCount = g.Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Year)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Month)
    .ThenBy(x => x.WeekNr)
    .ToList();
```

When it comes to allocating overtime, we've adopted a pro-rata basis method. This approach distributes the calculated overtime to the respective months based on the proportion of workdays that fall into each month within a given week. It provides a fair and systematic method for assigning overtime, particularly when weeks straddle two months.

Here's how the pro-rata allocation of overtime is implemented:

- **Calculate Total Weekly Overtime**: Ascertain the total overtime hours for each week without modifying the weekly hours threshold.
- **Join with `WeekInMonthDays`**: Determine how the week's workdays are distributed between months.
- **Allocate Overtime Pro-rata**: For weeks that extend over two months, apportion the overtime hours between the months in line with the workdays' distribution.

For instance, if an employee accrues 10 overtime hours in a week that has three workdays in one month and two in the following month, you would allocate 6 hours (60%) of the overtime to the first month and 4 hours (40%) to the second.

In closing, this focused approach does not take into account public holidays. If needed, holidays can easily be incorporated into the `WeekInMonthDays` list to ensure the overtime allocation reflects the actual working days more accurately.

Comment: how much of the text of this post was written by an AI?